# Python3 not actually killing processes

Tags: python, python-3.x, process

I'm running some processes from Python3 but they are not being terminated. This is a MCVE of the problem, running on Linux 16.04 with Python 3.5. I've tried this with QJoypad and with Sublime3.

```
import subprocess
import time

p_joypad = subprocess.Popen(['qjoypad'])   # also happens with sublime3
time.sleep(2)                              # wait until process starts

p_joypad.terminate()                       # try and kill it

p_joypad.kill()                            # try and kill it again
del p_joypad

os.kill(p_joypad.pid, signal.SIGTERM)      # ask the OS to kill it
os.kill(p_joypad.pid, signal.SIGKILL)

# another attempt at calling and killing the process
p_joypad = subprocess.Popen(['qjoypad'], preexec_fn=os.setsid)
os.killpg(os.getpgid(p_joypad.pid), signal.SIGTERM)

input("Process is still open, baby")       # hang up to verify this
```

Initially I had only the `terminate()` call, but then I tried the `kill()` as well as clearing the object from memory. However, both processes are still running after this. Qjoypad doesn't allow other instances to be called (so I need to close and restart my Python3 application), which is exceedingly problematic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the issue. I had to set `shell` to `True` and kill the process group. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789837/how-to-terminate-a-python-subprocess-launched-with-shell-true/4791612#4791612).

```
p_joypad = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
os.killpg(os.getpgid(p_joypad.pid), signal.SIGTERM)
```